# Hiding elements having specific attributes

Tags: javascript, html

I have a script which lists several thousand images, each in a separate div. Something like this:

```
<div class="imagecontainer">
  <img src="picturename.jpg">
</div>

<div class="imagecontainer">
  <img src="picturename2.jpg">
</div>
```

What I'm looking to do, is to somehow tag the divs with filesizes and dimensions, so it would be easy for me to hide duplicate image-divs, just by clicking on them. See below what im thinking:

```
<script>
function hide(filesize, imageheight, imagewidth) {
     HERE I NEED CODE TO HIDE ALL DIVS THAT HAS THE SPECIFIED FILESIZE, 
     IMAGEHEIGHT AND IMAGEWIDTH.
}
</script>

<div class="imagecontainer" filesize="279603" imageheight="500" imagewidth="380"
 onclick="hide('279603', '500', '380')">
  <img src="picturename.jpg">
</div>

<div class="imagecontainer" filesize="272655" imageheight="500" imagewidth="380"
 onclick="hide('272655', '500', '380')">
  <img src="picturename2.jpg">
</div>
```

Can you understand what I'm trying to do? I have no idea for valid ways to "tag" the divs for finding them based on these criteria. Maybe there's other ways to do it?

Comment: Why are you even identifying images by file size and dimensions, and not... file names? What if two images are exactly the same in size (which, let's face it, given "several thousand images" is *bound* to happen)?

Comment: because images come from an ebay type of site, so filenames are randomized, but can contain same image. and yes i know that this approach is not 100% foolproof, but its good enough for what i will be using it for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty simple if you use jQuery. It can be done in straight Javascript as well but with a little more effort.  Your function will be this:

```
<script>
 function hide(filesize, imageheight, imagewidth) {
    $('.imagecontainer[filesize="' + filesize + '"]' + '[imageheight="' + imageheight+ '"]' + '[imagewidth="' + imagewidth+ '"]').hide();
}
</script>
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsbin.com/lubojeve/2/edit?html,js,output)

Also, I'd recommend your attributes to: data-filesize, data-imageheight, and data-imagewidth so you are HTML compliant.

Comment: This will soooo slow.

Comment: Output of the above code ``Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [filesize="279603"[imageheight="500"[imagewidth="380"``

Comment: @true: How do you know?

Comment: @BoltLock Just looking at the code, I can tell that many iterations will need to be done, a `document.getElementsByTagName('*')` will most likely be called.

Comment: No problem. I didn't notice that a class selector could be used. Fixed fiddle and code block for performance improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the class name for each element, you can just get all elements with that class. The fastest way is to do a linear search on all elements.

```
function hide(filesize, imageheight, imagewidth) {
  filesize    = (filesize).toString();
  imageheight = (imageheight).toString();
  imagewidth  = (imagewidth).toString();

  var els = document.getElementsByClassName('imagecontainer');

  for(var i = 0; i < els.length; ++i) {
    var el = els[i];
    var fsize = el.getAttribute('filesize');
    var iheight = el.getAttribute('imageheight');
    var iwidth = el.getAttribute('imagewidth');

    if(fsize === filesize && imageheight === iheight && iwidth === imagewidth) {
       el.style.display='none'; 
       break;
    }           
  }
}
```